# Choosing a permutation of 10 digits 0,1,....9 in which

Tags: combinatorics

Choosing a permutation of 10 digits 0,1,....9 in which 5 is not in the first position amd 9 is not in the last position?

Soln:  What I wrote as an answer was: $$(9)(9)(8!)$$

but the answer in the back of the book says: $$[(1)(9)(8!) + (8)(8)(8!)]$$

I have no idea how could this come about.  If a 5 cannot be in the first position there are still 9 other choices,  same with the last position.  So why the difference?  what did i fail to consider?

Comment: If $5$ is not in the 1st position, then you have $9$ choices. But $9$ maybe chosen for the first position and then we have $9$ choices for the last position. This explains the part $1 \cdot 9 \cdot (8!)$. Suppose $9$ is not chosen in the first position, then we have $8$ choices for the first, and $8$ choices for the last. This explains the part $8 \cdot 8 \cdot (8!)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They broke it up into cases.

Case (i): $9$ is in the first position. Then the rest can be arranged in $9!$ ways.

Case (ii): Something else is in the first position. It can be any of $8$. anything but $5$ or $9$. Then the last position can be filled in $8$ ways, for we must avoid $9$, and the rest filled in $8!$ ways.

**Another way:** We do the counting in another way that however does not answer your question. There are $10!$ permutations. We count and subtract the *bad ones*, where there is a $5$ at the beginning, or a $9$ at the end, or both. There are $9!$ with $5$ at the beginning, and the same number with $9$ at the end. But $9!+9!$ double counts the $8!$ permutations that have $5$ at the beginning *and* $9$ at the end. Thus there are $2\cdot 9!-8!$ bad permutations, and therefore $10!-2\cdot 9!+8!$ good ones.

Comment: i still do not see why it is only $(1)(9)(8!)$. You say 9 may be in the first position,  but at the same time could 5 not be in the last position?   Why wouldn't all of these cases be encapsulated in my version of the solution?

Comment: It's OK for $5$ to be in last position.  In this part we are just counting the permutations that have $9$ first. These are all automatically good.

Comment: That is correct,  that is how I reasoned it,  but why are the only 8 legal choices?  Our only restriction is no 9?

Comment: Yes, you are right, and I said so in the answer! I will modify the comment.

Comment: Among the $9$ choices for first position counted by your $(9)$ is letting the first digit be say $3$. If we have chosen $3$ as first, then there are only $8$ choices for last position, for we can't use $3$ and we must avoid $9$. So one cannot write $(9)(9)$.

Comment: Ok I understand now.  I really thought I had taken account of all cases.  I guess the only way to improve at decomposing these questions is by attempting to write out more cases.   Thanks for the clarification

Comment: You are welcome. The problem here was a lack of independence, the later count changed depending on the first choice made.

Comment: So the independence condition is what prevented a straight multiplication and hence needing to break into separate cases and add.  I will remember to ask myself that question from here on out.  "are my sets indepemdent"

Comment: There is in counting always *set* dependence, the issue is count-dependence. One has to ask oneself whether for *every one* of the $k$ possible ways to do the "first" thing, there are $l$ ways to do the "second thing".

Answer (score 1):

There are 9 choices for the first place.  1 of those is 9.  8 of them are not 9.  If it *is* 9 there are are nine possible choices choices for the last place.  That's 1*9 possible ways to get the first position and the last position if the first position is 9.

If the first term is *not* 9 there are 8 possible choices for the last place (anything that isn't a 9 and isn't what the first position was).  The 9*8 ways to get the first position and the last position if the first position is not 9.

So in total there are [1*9 + 9*8] possible ways to get the first and last positions. (9 where the first position is "9"; 9*8 where it is not).

Then there are 8! for the remaining 8 positions.

In total there are  [1*9 + 9*8]8! possibilities.